# How to make ActivityIndicator overlay full screen?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a **StackLayout** and a number of elements inside (buttons, texts etc).
I want the **ActivityIndicator** to overlay the entire screen and make it not able to do anything to those elements.
I have put **ActivityIndicator** inside the **StackLayout** but wrapped it with AbsoluteLayout thinking that AbsoluteLayout can easitly overlap everything:

```
<StackLayout>
    <AbsoluteLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator ... />
    </AbsoluteLayout>
    <...other elements...> 
</StackLayout>
```

Instead activity indicator is displayed at the top of the StackLayout and other elements are available for affecting. I'm new in Xamarin and layouts, what am I doing wrong? All samples in the Internet have single ActivityIndicator per page...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It is better said that an `AbsoluteLayout`'s children can easily overlap each other. Just as a `StackLayout` lets you stack controls inside , vertically or horizontally, an `AbsoluteLayout` lets you position controls inside using absolute or proportional values, thus if two controls have the same absolute positioning set, they will overlap 100%.

Therefore, you want to wrap your `StackLayout` and another `StackLayout` that has your `ActivityIndicator` inside an `AbsoluteLayout` using proportional sizing, e.g:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <StackLayout
        x:Name="mainLayout"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                 AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" >
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Do Something"
                Clicked="DoSomethingBtn_Clicked" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout
        x:Name="aiLayout"
        IsVisible="False"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
        BackgroundColor="Gray" Opacity="0.5">
        <ActivityIndicator
            x:Name="ai"
            IsRunning="False"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            Color="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The above sets the two `StackLayouts` to both take up the full size of the parent container of the AbsoluteLayout, which is presumably a Page. The `StackLayout` that has the indicator is initially hidden. IN the page code behind for the above example, I show the second `StackLayout` and start the activity indicator and show it for 2 seconds, and then hide it again:

```
    private async void DoSomethingBtn_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ai.IsRunning = true;
        aiLayout.IsVisible = true;
        await Task.Delay(2000);
        aiLayout.IsVisible = false;
        ai.IsRunning = false;

    }
```

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

And since the second `StackLayout` completely covers the first, none of the controls in the first `StackLayout` are clickable.

Might be worth going over the docs for the AbsoluteLayout to understand the AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds and AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout

Comment: Thank you for a detailed answer! Can you please tell me if I can create and show ActivityIndicator dynamically on multiple pages? I have tens of pages and most of them need to make web requests, so I need to display this indicator. Should I put the indicator into every single page or I'd better have a single ContentView with an indicator which I'd show as modal dialog? THanks again!

Comment: You could make a ContentView and then add that ContentView to each page. Or you could make a Content page and present it modally. There are so many options on how to handle this, so what you end up do is up to you.

Comment: This was a life saver Just going to add if you want the Indicator Bigger just use The Scale Property

Answer (score 6):

If you want to "overlap", you need to be outside of the StackLayout. A Grid is the most common control for this:

```
<Grid>
  <StackLayout>
        <...other elements...> 
  </StackLayout>
  <ActivityIndicator ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can go outside the bounds of a control using `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Here, he is talking about a StackLayout and AbsoluteLayout. There's nothing wrong about my answer... RelativeLayout can also do overlaps. But in case you don't know, this layout is more or less not recommended. See https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips (from Jason Smith former XF team). Cordially

Comment: I meant that this won't work unless the `Grid` is the root element of the entire app, which is not always possible _(for example, it won't work if the app uses `NavigationPage`)_

Comment: A Grid will NEVER be the root element of the entire app. It MUST be something inheriting from Page (TabbePage, NavigationPage, Shell, ..).  I give an answer. You say it's wrong and you will always argue with more and more arguments (that are not legit  by the way) BUT EVERYTHING I wrote in this answer is correct + links I gaved are from people that create XF. That's not a question of who is the best, I don't care but please... That's my last message I promise

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hacked-up control for making things full-screen via the horribly-named `RelativeLayout` *(tested in Android only)*

```
    [ContentProperty("ContentInner")]
    public class FullScreenLayout : ContentView
    {
        public View ContentInner
        {
            get => ((RelativeLayout) Content).Children[0];
            set
            {
                var display = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
                var screenWidth = display.Width / display.Density;
                var screenHeight = display.Height / display.Density;
                var wrapper = new RelativeLayout();
                wrapper.Children.Add(value, () => new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight));
                Content = wrapper;
            }
        }
    }
```

It can be used like this:

```
<controls:FullScreenLayout>
  <!-- Anything you want fullscreen here -->
</controls:FullScreenLayout>
```

---

Unfortunately, if you use `NavigationPage`, **this won't overlap the navigation bar.**  Every other solution currently on this page has the same issue.  According to [this question](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/430604), it's not possible to solve this without using platform-specific customer renderers.  Ugh.

If you don't mind the page being dimmed, you can use [Rg.Plugins.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) which implements the custom renderers needed.

---

I ended up solving my similar problem *(dimming most of the screen)* by implementing a custom renderer for the navigation page itself.

Comment: An other one from MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relativelayout => "Avoid using a RelativeLayout whenever possible. It will result in the CPU having to perform significantly more work."

Comment: @RudySpano We're laying out one child, so that shouldn't be relevant here. Also it doesn't seem to even be possible to implement this with other layout types, so performance comparisons are moot.

Comment: There's nothing complicated in the initial request... Perhaps you're the only one  to really understand the request...? (VS all other votes and interractions). I can ensure you if you're using your FullScreenLayout , you can achieve the same behvior with out of the box layouts and controls. Anyway, OK that's your choice. (+ the thred is  1 year+)

Comment: @RudySpano: Answering old questions is not only allowed, it's actively encouraged. The point is not to help the initial asker, but to help future googlers with the same problem.